# Timer is not working in cross threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer

I have 2 global `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` in my **form**. Both are initialized in form's constructor. But not started yet. Constructor starts a **new thread** and that thread enables and starts both of the timers. Obviously it is all **cross threading**, but it doesn't throw any cross-thread exception. But it doesn't even work. It does not fire the `Timer.Tick` method. Here is the code:

**1st Method:**

In form constructor:

```
    KeepMeAliveTimer = new Timer();  //timer 1
    KeepMeAliveTimer.Interval = 15000;            
    KeepMeAliveTimer.Tick += KeepMeAlive;
    timer1 = new Timer();   //timer 2
    timer1.Interval = 15000;
    timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
    //started a new thread
```

In new thead:

```
    //after performing some tasks, it enables the timers
    KeepMeAliveTimer.Enabled = true;  //timer 1
    KeepMeAliveTimer.Start();
    timer1.Enabled = true;   //timer 2
    timer1.Start();
```

But it is not firing up Timer's tick events and not even throwing any exception.

**2nd Method:**

But when I initialized and enabled the `Timers` in the same thread (Main Thread) they are working perfectly:

```
    KeepMeAliveTimer = new Timer();   //timer 1
    KeepMeAliveTimer.Interval = 15000;            
    KeepMeAliveTimer.Tick += KeepMeAlive;
    KeepMeAliveTimer.Enabled = true;
    KeepMeAliveTimer.Start();
    timer1 = new Timer();    //timer 2
    timer1.Interval = 15000;
    timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick; 
    timer1.Enabled = true; 
    timer1.Start();
```

Now the question is; Why the first method is not working if there is not even any exception?

Comment: The exceptions ae an extra (debugging aid). No guarantees that it's airtight.  Your code isn't thread-safe and it isn't working. `1+1=2`.

Comment: And to be complete, specify which Timer class (namespace). .NET has at least 3.

Comment: The System.Windows.Forms.Timer relies on the Windows Message Queue getting pushed to it I believe. If it is on a thread without access the the Message Queue it can't do anything.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Using .net 4.5... class is `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. I know code isn't thread safe, but i just want to know the reason that why is it not working?

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint at 'KeepMeAliveTimer.Enabled = true;'? (Or is your task throwing an exception already)?

Comment: @Brad You mean i should use `System.Timers.Timer` ?

Comment: @FabianBigler Yes every thing is fine, i have even checked using `messagebox` to show its current state, both are enabled. And no there is no exception of any type.

Comment: @Shaharyar I think that has a similar issue. See Hans's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Timer class is thread-safe but not in the way you expect it.  Calling the Start() method on worker thread does actually start the timer.  The class goes through the effort of creating a hidden window so it can call the SetTimer winapi function and receive the WM_TIMER message when it is done.

But the Tick event cannot be raised if nobody is listening for that message.  You won't be, surely you didn't call Application.Run() on that thread.  You should therefore not start a timer on a worker thread.  Use Control.BeginInvoke if necessary to get it started on the UI thread.

Or use a System.Threading.Timer or System.Timers.Timer, they don't depend on a message loop.  You do have to interlock properly, their Elapsed event or callback run on yet *another* thread.  Which is the kind of solution that tends to create another problem.

Comment: But there is no `BeginInvoke` method in the `Timer` class

Comment: Great answer ! cleared concepts and implementation works perfectly